# Help with AC analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

Can someone help me solve this? The answer is at the top right:

[image]

This is what I tried; can someone show me what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: The sources are cosines, not sines, so the first source is \$60\angle{(20+90)}=20.52-j56.38\$. Don't forget about the 2nd one.

Comment: Why don't you put together a simulation and check some of your intermediate results?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to analyze this is to redraw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa0GuR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are allowed to re-arrange series components. You are also allowed to select your "ground" reference. (I picked the (-) node for that.)

This greatly simplifies things because all you have now is a voltage divider between \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$. In general, the solution for such dividers comes from the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzuLeE.png)</sup>

The general solution is \$V_x=\frac{V_1\cdot Z_2 + V_2\cdot Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2}\$.

So, in your case you have:

$$V_x=\frac{V_1\cdot \left(Z_{C_1}+Z_{L_2}+Z_{C_2}+R_2\right) + V_2\cdot \left(Z_{L_1}+R_1\right)}{Z_{L_1}+R_1+Z_{C_1}+Z_{L_2}+Z_{C_2}+R_2}$$

You can easily work out that \$V_1\approx 56.38156+20.52121j\$ and \$V_2=100+0j\$. (Luckily, both power supplies are operating with \$\omega=50\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$.)

From a calculator program I wrote years ago, I get:

```
[ (56.38156+20.52121j)*(10mF+50mH+5mF+5) + 100*(100mH+2) ] / [10mF+50mH+5mF+5+100mH+2]
    
Answer: 87.4932708 + 39.1472405 j
        95.851859 at 24.1052432 degrees
```

Which is pretty close to the answer values.

Comment: Simple and to the point, keeping the sine as the reference, without adjusting them to cosines (now I see I have a sign typo in my comment).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks. Since it's just a matter of "between these two points" and since I can just "ground" one of them, it has to work out.